# NSURLSession track multiple get requests?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I used to do what I wanted with `NSURLConnection`.

- I would create a new custom `NSOperation` object
- setup my `NSMutalbeRequest` and when ready trigger the `operation` witch would queue the operation...
- in there I would have the `NSURLConnection` `delegate` methods and with that I could track all progress, completion, errors etc...

So, the point is, request would be contained in its own `operation` and the `delegate` calls would happen in there, **having a 1-to-1 relationship between the request operation object and the `NSURLConnection delegate`**.

I am not sure HOW to do this with a `NSURLSession`. With the `NSURLSession` I can trigger all the dataTasks I want for all the GET calls I want to perform.
However I setup the **shared** session using this call:

```
+ (NSURLSession *)sessionWithConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration delegate:(id <NSURLSessionDelegate>)delegate delegateQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue;
```

So the problem I am trying to solve is **how can I track multiple GET requests progress if I have only one object where all the delegate calls happen**? I only have ONE DELEGATE in there. So now I have 1 session, 1 delegate object but I have multiple GET requests happening at the same time.

I know each task has a "taskIdentifier", but that requires me to have some kind of dictionary.

For example when the delegate call:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

is called, then I'd have to look up the task in a dictionary and then the object I'd get from the dictionary could have the reference to what I need to track the progress of that one request...

I am not sure what the best way to solve this problem is? Does anybody know how this should be done?

Comment: Your dictionary solution sounds ok. What kind of tracking do you need / situation do you think will be a problem?

Comment: The way you said is exactly what you have to do, since each data task needs to append to its own mutable data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the data from a finished \`NSURLSessionDataTask\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924483/how-do-i-get-the-data-from-a-finished-nsurlsessiondatatask)

Comment: @matt: that link you posted is more towards how to get data out of the task.... I know how to do that, I am more concerned on how to structure things to manage multiple concurrent requests from the same delegate through which all the requests go through...

Comment: No, look at Rob's comprehensive answer.

Comment: The way I've seen this done is using objc_setAssociatedObject to staple a subsidiary object to the task, but I'm not sure that's any cleaner than a dictionary.

Comment: Why not just create a new session for each GET, which then maps easily to your old method with NSURLConnection?   What is the advantage of sharing a single session?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So,

what worked best for me so far is using the NSDictionary approach. That allows the NSURLSession delegates to get a hold of the right data task and handle multiple requests at once.

I am not sure if this is the best approach, but my app is now running lots of requests and things seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is set accessibility label for each requests

```
    for task 1

    [dataTask setAccessibilityLabel:@"label1"];

    for task 2

    [dataTask setAccessibilityLabel:@"label2"];
```

and then in delegate methods check for accessibility label

```
    if([dataTask.accessibilityLabel  isEqual: @"label1"])
     {
        // handle data from first task

     }

     if([dataTask.accessibilityLabel  isEqual: @"label2"])
     {
       // handle data from second task

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also instantiate the NSURLSessionDataTask with your own subclass of NSURLRequest which you can retrieve from task.originalRequest in the session delegate.

Comment: I liked this idea and it works great for NSURLRequest.  However, I tried same idea for an NSMutableURLRequest and that failed.  After casting task.originalRequest to my subclass, it aborted with unknown method on NSMutableURLRequest.